# What is the difference between these two loops?

Tags: while-loop, do-while

I want to write a loop in which I increase my variable i, until arr[i] is less or equal than v.

I've tried these two loops but only the first loop is working and I can't tell the difference.

first loop:

```java
do{
   i++;
   if(arr[i] >= v)
     break;
}while(true);
```

second loop:

```java
do{
   i++;
}while(arr[i] <= v)
```

I was wondering what exactly the second loop is doing that I don't get the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first one you are breaking when the value is greater than or equal to v

In the second one you are breaking when the value is greater than v

The break conditions are different for each loop

For the second one to work correctly,

```
do{
   i++;
}while(arr[i] < v)
```